# How to add class to li tag in react-slick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

I'm using the [`react-slick`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-slick) library. I've checked API [docs](https://react-slick.neostack.com/), but not found any props to set a `li` tag class.

**how I can add my custom class names?**

[image]

Comment: Do the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) not cover styling well enough? Please update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example and details on what isn't working and what your expected result should be. As written it is unclear what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your custom `className` to the wrapper then in your CSS file select the `li` children and inject your styles, like below:

```js
const settings = {
  className: 'customName', // <== your custom name
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1
};
```

And in your CSS file:

```css
.customName li {
  border: 1px solid red; /* it's just an example */
}
```